# How can I unload Oracle database tables into a csv files?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, export, command-line

I need to retrieve certain data from an Oracle 11g release 1 database and provide it as one or more CSV files. The data resides in multiple tables and/or views. All this should work via the command line.
What would be the best approach to this?

Answer (score 11):

Arun,

now that sqlcl is available from[Oracle SQL Developer 4.1 EA2 (4.1.0.18.37)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/sqldev-41ea-2372780.html)
you can use it a lot like the old and famous sqlplus.
sqlcl has an output format setting for csv

```
set sqlformat csv
spool x.csv
select * from yourtable[s];
spool off
```

for more info about sqlcl checkout [Kris' blog](http://krisrice.blogspot.nl/)

before sqlcl was around
easiest for this was to use APEX and export the report to csv.
In plain old sqlplus you can do this by using

```
set lines 9999 -- the appropriate size
set head off  -- no header lines
set colsep ';' --column separator to ;
set pages 0 -- no pages
set feed off
select your data;
spool to_tofile
/
spool off
```

This works best if the results are to be written on an application server or client. If they have to be written on the database server, utl_file might be a better option.

Ronald.

Answer (score 8):

You should look at the built in [UTL_FILE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_file.htm#ARPLS70896) package.  There are several ways you could use it.

1. You could write any number of procedures in packages that use the UTL_FILE package to write to any number of files.  These procedures can then be called from almost any application including SQL*Plus.
2. You could write a PL/SQL script to do the same work and call the script from the SQL*Plus command line itself by specifying @scriptname on the command line.
3. You could paste a block using UTL_FILE directly into SQL*Plus, but this should only be used for one time exports and even then it might not be the best route.

In their simplest a file export using UTL_FILE would be composed of a call to [FOPEN](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_file.htm#i1003526), one or more calls to [PUT_LINE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_file.htm#i997640), and a call to [FCLOSE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e16760/u_file.htm#i1003326).

Answer (score 4):

If performance is a concern, you may want to consider tools from vendors.

I have evaluated tools from BMC, Wisdomforce, CoSort, DBCrane. They are all significantly faster than spool, utl_file or external table. We are using [DBCrane](http://www.bronzeage.us/downloads.html) because my boss didn't want to spend too much on license.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Python and cx_Oracle module to extract data to disk in CSV format.

Here’s how you connect to Oracle using cx_Oracle:

```
constr='scott/tiger@localhost:1521/ORCL12'
con = cx_Oracle.connect(constr)
cur = con.cursor()
```

After data fetch you can loop through Python list and save data in CSV format.

```
for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks(cur)):
    f_out.write('\n'.join([column_delimiter.join(row[0]) for row in chunk]))
    f_out.write('\n')
```

I used this approach when I wrote [TableHunter-For-Oracle](https://github.com/oracletools/table-hunter-for-oracle)