# Export data tables from SQLPlus

Tags: oracle, export, dump

Is there any way to export data from an Oracle SQLPlus console, without using the `exp` or `expdp` commands? I don't have sysdba privileges.

I'm not a real Oracle guru so I'm using Navicat to export but it just takes too long. I would prefer to do it locally from command line, but don't know how.

I have 1 day until they close down the server and I really need that data.

Comment: Have you tried Oracle's SQL Developer tool for this purpose? It's free and I've always found it to be very good. I honestly don't think that you'll get any **great** increase in speed from the command line anyway. How much data do you have? And why is it now so urgent to get what is essentially a backup? If your dump won't run in the required time, then contact your host and pay for an extra day/week/whatever. How much is your data worth to you?

Comment: well, not it exported like 30mb worth of like 500k rows in 2 hrs, with Navicat

Comment: I have like 70 million rows in the whole database...

Comment: You're telling me that it is going to take approx. 2 weeks to export ~ 5GB? Something is seriously wrong somewhere.

Comment: yeah... I am trying the dev tool from oracle.. I think that will spped things up.. Navicat is relying on my connection with the server through a VPN and tunnel, and exporting in plain sql format one row per line.. so that's why is very slow ..I think

Comment: and yes Oracle's SQL Developer is 20x faster, wrote in 2 minutes what navicat wrote in 2 hrs ~ 500k rows

Comment: You don't need DBA privileges to use `exp`.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-can-i-unload-oracle-database-tables-into-a-csv-files

Answer (score 0):

SQL*Developer is a decent tool for this, but can still take some time.

If you're looking at SQL Plus, I'd recommend that you use spool, and make liberal use of SQL Plus's [set command](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-sqlplus-set.html) to format your output into flat files. For delimiting the flat files, you can make use of the concatenate feature to add in column headers. Here's an example:

```
select 'col1,col2,col3,col4'
  from dual
union
select col1||','||col2||','||col3||','||col4
  from some_table;
```

HTH.